# After Extending Identity Provider - Error in manager.CreateIdentity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have followed the instructions [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity#userclass) to extend asp.net identity to use an int instead of a string for the user Id as I am adding identity to an existing database.

However, when I attempt to login I am getting the error: 
**The 'Id' property on 'IdentityRole`2' could not be set to a 'System.String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int32'.**

That happens in this class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(GenerateUserIdentity(manager));
    }

    public ClaimsIdentity GenerateUserIdentity(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity<ApplicationUser, int>(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

on the line

```
var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity<ApplicationUser, int>(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get a similar issue to this, it was that the Database was out of sync with the models, so I needed to change the RoleId in the AspNetRoles (and AspNetUserRoles) to an int in this case also.